# SQL Oracle: разница во времени(минута)

Tags: sql, oracle

Просьба, подсказать,
как можно получить разницу времени в минутах,
к примеру чтобы получить разницу с разрывном в несколько суток, через `trunc` нахожу разницу и уже дальше перевожу в минуты :

```
select trunc(sysdate - (sysdate-7))*1440 from dual
```

мне нужно получить, разницу в минутах при условии что в качестве переменных будет передано 2 временного значения (начальная и конечная точка).
для примера:

```
 select sysdate, sysdate-1/1440*(3) from dual
```

есть 2 временные точки, на выходе нужно получить 3,
но, если интервал между точками превышает час или сутки также на выходе получить количество минут,
можно ли как то универсально это выполнить?

попробую привести сценарий использования:
на вход будут поданы начальная и конечная точка `(sysdate и sysdate-1/1440*(3)` разница между входными данными 3 минуты(т.е. интервал расчета данных 3 минуты),
далее в запросе я сравниваю предыдущий интервал (3 минуты) с интервалом который был подан на входящие данные, соответственно я пытаюсь получить разницу и дальше уже выстраивать окна расчета на основе полученного интервала,
ранее строил суточный запрос, где разница между входящими данными составляет несколько суток или 1 сутки т.е. на вход получил `(sysdate и (sysdate-7))` соответственно рассчитывал расчетные периоды след. способом:

```
where time >= (sysdate-7) - trunc(sysdate - (sysdate-7)) 
and time < (sysdate-7)
```

соответственно сейчас столкнулся с затруднением, как более универсально можно расчитывать интервал между входными данными для дальнейшего использования, если разница между входными точками может несколько минут, часов или суток

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат разницы двух дат всегда кол-во дней, т.е. его надо просто  умножить на кол-во минут в сутках:

```
with t (starttime, endtime) as (
    select to_date ('01:00', 'hh24:mi') , to_date ('02:18', 'hh24:mi') from dual
)
select starttime, endtime, (endtime-starttime)*24*60 minutes
from t;

STARTTIME           ENDTIME                MINUTES
------------------- ------------------- ----------
2022-08-01 01:00:00 2022-08-01 02:18:00         78
```

Comment: Это при условии что дни разные, а если мне нужно найти разницу в минутах в сегодняшнем дне в разрезе какого то часа?

Comment: Что такое - _разрез какого то часа_? Какой у вас ожидаемый результат?

Comment: к примеру есть
select sysdate, sysdate-1/1440*(3) from dual
как я могу получить разницу между ними, пробовал через trunc не выходит, нужно получить на выходе 3, при этом если разница будет превышать час то также в минута, к пример 78

Comment: Почему вы написали комментарий, всю информацию надо в вопрос добавить.  Почему вы не попробуете пример в ответе? Что там не соответствует тому, что написано в вашем комментарии?

Comment: не совсем удобны было заполнять с телефона, скорректировал вопрос, написал что пытаюсь получить

Comment: Вынужден повторится, что в ответе не соответствует тому, что написано в вашем вопросе или комментарии? Запустите с вашими данными и поясните - ожидал то-то, а получил то-то.

Comment: дико извинясь за задержку...
как описал выше и дополнил в вопросе, на вход будет передаваться 2 переменные, для примера (sysdate и sysdate-1/1440*(3)) и мне нужно получить разницу между ними в минутах, 
при этом разница между переменными может быть как 2 минуты так и 30 часов и на выходе нужно получить цифру в минутах, ваш вариант с interval рабочий, но не совсем подходит

Comment: _ваш вариант с interval рабочий, но не совсем подходит_, так a почему не подходит? `sysdate-1/1440*(3)` и  `sysdate-interval '3' minute` в этом контексте абсолютно идентичны.

Comment: interval больше применим если я на вход подам значения расчетного периода в минутах,
из этого уже смогу рассчитать начальную и конечную, 
но я на вход подаю начальную и конечную точку и разница между ними может быть как 3 минуты так и 30 часов, соотвественно хочу получить эту разницу(в минутах) чтобы использовать дальше  в расчетах(запросе),

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил сценарий использования и в какой момент столкнулся с затруднением

Comment: @xcplat обновил ответ

Comment: благодарю, то что нужно